# Calling volley in onresume is not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-volley

This issue is weird. I have a function named callVolley() in my onresume of fragment,

```
  @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        callVolley();
    }
```

and callvolley does this :

```
void callVolley()
{
 System.out.println("Call123 In Async On mparams test" + URL + " " + mparams);

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                URL, mparams,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Parseresponce(response + "", mparams);
                        System.out.println("Call123 In Async On Responce " + URL + " " + response.toString());

                        Log.d("Response","Response : "+URL +"\n"+response.toString());

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Parseresponce(null, mparams);
                System.out.println("Call123 In Async On Responce Error: " + URL + " " + error.getMessage());
                Log.d("Response", "Error : "+URL +"\n"+error.toString());

            }
        });

        Cancelrequest();
        queue.add(jsonObjReq);
}
```

now onresume is called when the fragment is created as well as when we resume the app.
so when the fragment is created the volley function works properly.
but when i resume the app, the process is followed but the volley does not give any value. why does this happen?

Comment: The code on `onCreate` will probably be necessary.

Comment: oncreate is empty, and in oncreateview i just give the layout, and i call the method in the onresume method

Comment: Hi i am facing the same issue,did you find any solution? @Parth Anjaria